# Trying to use bulksms.com API using guzzle in Laravel but returning errors

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-5.8, bulksms

I have been trying to use guzzle for sending bulk sms from bulksms.com and it is returning this error,

> guzzlehttp\exception\clientexception client error: post
>   https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages resulted in a 401 full
>   authentication is required to access this resource response: : "type"
>   "https://developer.bulksms.com/json/v1/errors#authentication-failed

My code

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri'=>'https://www.bulksms.com/',
    'timeout'=>'900.0'
]); 

//$result = $client->post('', [
//    'form_params' => [
//        'sample-form-data' => 'value'
//    ]
//]);

$result = $client->request('POST','https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages', [
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => '****',
        'sender' => 'my appname',
        'recipients' => '+5555555555',
        'message' => 'Testing message',
    ]
]);
```

Comment: check the credential again which you are passing. like uname and password

Comment: This require basic authorization as per the document please send the authorization header with basic credentials

Comment: @DhavalPurohit — The error message is linking to "authentication-failed" (Verification of credentials failed) not "authentication-required" (No credentials were provided).

Comment: @Quentin credential are correct!

Comment: have you tried with header Authorization?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit how can you please guide to do that plz, thanks!

Comment: `$result = $client->request('POST','https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages', [
    'form_params' => [
        'sender' => 'my appname',
        'recipients' => '+5555555555',
        'message' => 'Testing message',
    ],
    'auth' => ['username', 'password']
]);`

Comment: Like this one. @tinox

Comment: @DhavalPurohit thanks for help, somethings changed but still have some errors,
Client error: `POST https://www.bulksms.com/` resulted in a `405 Not Allowed` response:

Comment: try this one.
$result = $client->request('POST','https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages', [ 'json' => [ "to"=>"+91xxxx","body"=>"message body" ], 'auth' => ['username', 'password'] ]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202652/discussion-between-tinox-and-dhaval-purohit).

Comment: @DhavalPurohit now am getting this error
Client error: `POST api.bulksms.com/v1/messages` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "type" : "https://developer.bulksms.com/json/v1/errors#bad-request", "title" : "Bad Request", "status" : 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people have already pointed you towards using authentication correctly, and using JSON as the format of your request. Additionally, you're using the wrong variable names. For example, the documentation uses the variable name `to`, and you have used `recipients` instead (maybe you copied and pasted that code from somewhere else?).

The documentation has a PHP code sample the uses curl, at: https://www.bulksms.com/developer/json/v1/#tag/Message - why not use that as a basis, and then convert it to a working Guzzle request, as a starting point?

Comment: How? please help am new to this Curl stuff! 
can you provide sample code please! @PaoloC

Comment: this is the error I am getting right now
Client error: `POST https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages/` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "type" : "https://developer.bulksms.com/json/v1/errors#bad-request", "title" : "Bad Request", "status" : 400, (truncated...)

Comment: my code 
$result = $client->request('POST','/v1/messages/', [ 
            'json' => [ 
                'from' => 'App name',
                'type'=> 'string',
                'title'=> 'string',
                'status'=> 0,
                'detail'=> 'string',
                'to' => '+101221',
                'body' => 'Testing message',
                'Content-Type'=>'application/json',
                'Authorization'=> 'Basic '. base64_encode("$username:$password")
                 ], 
                'auth' => ['username', '*****',
            ] 
        ]);

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [Authentication section](https://www.bulksms.com/developer/json/v1/#section/Authentication) in the API docs? 
You should authenticate with the API using HTTP Basic Auth.